# How to convert a string to ASCII value in PHP without ord()?

Tags: php, ascii

I am looking to convert a string say 'Hello' world to its ASCII value in php.
But I don't want to use `ord()`. Are there any other solutions for printing ascii value without using `ord()`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `ord`?

Comment: That's like saying I want to go out in the rain and don't want to get wet but I don't want to use an umbrella.. A PHP native function exists to solve your problem perfectly, but you'd rather write something from scratch?

Answer (score 32):

[`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

> Unpacks from a binary string into an array according to the given format.

Use the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php#refsect1-function.pack-parameters) `C*` to return everything as what you'd get from `ord()`.

```
print_r(unpack("C*", "Hello world"));
```

```
Array
(
    [1] => 72
    [2] => 101
    [3] => 108
    [4] => 108
    [5] => 111
    [6] => 32
    [7] => 119
    [8] => 111
    [9] => 114
    [10] => 108
    [11] => 100
)
```

Comment: nice, I like that

Comment: And you can further use `implode` to combine the array values to a string like this: `implode('', unpack("C*", "Hello world"))` returns `7210110810811132119111114108100`

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over each character in the string, find its offset into a dictionary string using say **strpos**, then add on a base number eg **65** if your dictionary started with "**ABC**...

You'd need to handle unfound characters, so maybe better to use a dictionary of "**#ABC**... then add a base of **64**, obviously you'd need to test for "#" as a special character then.

You could even test against multiple distionary strings for limited character sets "**#A..Z**", "**#a..z**", "**#0..9**"

You get the idea, but without knowing why you want to limit yourself I can't tell whther this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `iconv` native function:

```
string iconv ( string $in_charset , string $out_charset , string $str )
```

So it would be:

```
<?php
$string = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII", $string), PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Taken from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: I wonder why this `iconv()` function allows any unicode character to slip through. Take any [unicode character](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) and you'll see that it passes through, even when using `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $string)`