# convert to ascii and then to byte

Tags: php

in this code snippet i want to convert my value to ascii (comment) and i used ord function and i dont know it is correct or not and then i want to convert it to byte and my problem is how can i do that?

```
$time=time();
$timeStamp = date("Ymdhis",$time).'<br>';
$serviceID = '98012000018449';
$price = '3000';
$cpCode = '';
$requestID = rand(1,100);
$key = $serviceID + $serviceID + $price + $timeStamp + $requestID;
$encodedKey = ord($key);//here i want convert to asccii
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unpack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

```
print_r(unpack("C*", $key));
```

This will give you the same output as ord()

```
Array
(
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 49
    [3] => 54
    [4] => 49
    [5] => 57
    [6] => 53
    [7] => 48
    [8] => 50
    [9] => 50
    [10] => 49
    [11] => 48
    [12] => 51
    [13] => 55
    [14] => 55
    [15] => 48
)
```

And in this answer you can find more info

[How to convert a string to ASCII value in php without ord()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398502/how-to-convert-a-string-to-ascii-value-in-php-without-ord)